# How do blocks signal whether it supports classic Ethereum or any other soft fork on the Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum

Is there a “bit signal” in the soft fork activation mechanism in the Ethereum blockchain, like in Bitcoin, if not, how does it work in Ethereum?
(https://www.visualcapitalist.com/mapping-major-ethereum-forks/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ethereum doesn't do soft forks, only hard forks. The graphic on the site you linked is inaccurately referring to some as soft forks. Hard forks in Ethereum are just planned ahead for a set block and everyone that wants to be on the updated chain updates their client. If they don't update, they'll be on the old chain, which likely wont have any miners

Answer (score 1):

There is no such mechanism in Ethereum.